# How to get latest version of specific project in TFS using Powershell.

Tags: powershell, tfs

I've look through many posts but still don't get it.  I need a powershell script to download latest version of a specific project.

Let's say I just want to download the latest copies of files from ProjectA branch dfe.  I saw some PS script that deletes the old files and download all the files again but that takes too long. script that would overwrite existing files would be much better.  I tried update-tfsworkspace, it downloads everything but I don't want to download everything.
server: http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

DefaultCollection
 ProjectA
 -Folder1 
  - branch dfe
 -Folder2
  - branch abc

ProjectB
 -Folder1
  - branch
  - branch

Answer (score 3):

First you need a good workspace mapping. You can create one manually, or from an xml file as below. Also, the functionality you are after to overwrite is [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::Overwrite

```
function Get-ProjectXml {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $tfs13Url,
    [string] $workspaceName ,
    [string] $workspaceDescription,
    [string] $fileName,
    [bool] $autoDeleteCreate)

    try
    { 
        #Connect to TFS:
        $tfs13 = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($tfs13url)
        $vcs13 = $tfs13.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])

        $workspaces=$vcs13.QueryWorkspaces($workspaceName, $vcs13.AuthenticatedUser, [Environment]::MachineName);
        if($autoDeleteCreate ){
            #Delete if Workspace exists, as this is an automated process...
            if ($workspaces.count -gt 0)
            {
                $vcs13.DeleteWorkspace($workspaceName, $vcs13.AuthenticatedUser);
            }
            $workspace = $tfs10.VCS.CreateWorkspace($workspaceName, $vcs13.AuthenticatedUser, $workspaceDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            $workspace=$workspaces[0]
        }
        #Get XML File
        [xml]$xmlMappings= New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $xmlMappings.Load($fileName)
        $rootLocalItem=$xmlMappings.Root.LocalItem

        #Iterate through each collection
        foreach($collection in $xmlMappings.Collection){
            write-host "Mapping project $($collection.Name)"

            #Iterate through each project
            foreach($project in $collection.Project){
            write-host "Mapping project $($project.Name)"
            foreach($mapping in $project.Mapping){
                $workspace.Map($mapping.ServerItem, $mapping.LocalItem);
               }
            }
        }            
        $resultTime= Measure-Command {
            $result=$workspace.Get([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest,[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::Overwrite)
        }
        $resultAlerts=$result.NumConflicts+ $result.NumFailures+ $result.NumWarnings
        if ($resultAlerts -eq 0) {
            Write-host "Get Operation completed without any errors. $($result.NumUpdated) files are updated on workspace: $($workspace.name)" }
        else {
            Write-Host "Get Operation completed with errors. Please check errors: $($result.GetFailures)"}
            $resultTime.ToString()
    }
    catch
    {
        return $_.exception
    }
}
[string] $tfs13Url="http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection",
[string] $workspaceName = "AutomatedWorkspace",
[string] $workspaceDescription = "AutomatedWorkspace",
[string] $fileName="D:\projects\ProjectMapping.xml",
[bool] $autoDeleteCreate =$true 

Get-ProjectXml $tfs13Url $workspaceName $workspaceDescription $fileName $autoDeleteCreate
```

Assuming your xml is like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Collection Name="DefaultCollection">
      <Root>
        <ServerItem>$/</ServerItem>
        <LocalItem>d:\Src</LocalItem>
      </Root>
      <Project name="ProjectA">
        <Mapping>
          <ServerItem>$/ProjectA/Folder1/BranchDEF</ServerItem>
          <LocalItem>d:\Src\ProjectA\Folder1\BranchDEF\</LocalItem>
        </Mapping>
        <Mapping>
          <ServerItem>$/ProjectA/Folder2\BranchABC</ServerItem>
          <LocalItem>d:\Src\ProjectA\Folder2\BranchABC</LocalItem>
        </Mapping>
     </Project>
     <Project Name="ProjectB">
        <Mapping>
          <ServerItem>$/ProjectB/Folder5\BranchXYZ</ServerItem>
          <LocalItem>d:\Src\ProjectB\Folder5\BranchXYZ</LocalItem>
        </Mapping>
     </Project>
    </Collection>
```